# How do I prevent scroll back up with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage where there is a full height intro image. Underneath this image is the main body of the site with a regular site header at the top, I'm trying to create an effect where once the user scrolls down to the site header, they cannot scroll back up to view the intro image.

[image: Example Image]

**CSS Classes:**

Main Intro Image: `.cq-fullscreen-intro`

Site Header: `.nav-down`

I had a poke around on StackOverflow but I can't find anything that addresses this circumstance, can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: I don't think there is something builtin to jQuery that can do this, but you could watch for scroll events and check if the site header is at the top of the window, then change the "main intro image" to `display: none`.

Comment: Preventing a user from being able to scroll for any reason is a horrible decision in terms user experience. As a user, if I couldn't scroll up and didn't know why, I can only imagine how absolutely frustrating that would be. Generally speaking, it's almost *never* a good idea to override default browser behavior with your own; you have to remember that not every user is using a computer, or a mouse, or a device that will play nicely with your custom implementations, etc. Not to mention that it's more difficult to program than just hiding the intro when it first scrolls out of view.

Comment: @TylerRoper I would normally agree but I'm trying to combine this effect with one where scrolling down snaps the viewport down to the main site content, this way the intro screen and remainder of the site are clearly separated.

Comment: @Van Understood - however I don't believe that discounts my comment. After you snap the page down and the top/intro is no longer visible, why not just hide it entirely? The user would not be able to scroll up at that point because there's no longer any content there.

Comment: People should be cautious about using the word scroll / scrolling.  It generally implies that the user has the capability to move content vertically or horizontally.  I think a better description would be, *how do I show a `splash screen` and animate it off the screen*.

Comment: I'd also mention that allowing the user to determine the speed and duration of the transition between *splash screen* and *main screen* is also poor experience.  Can I use the main screen while I have them in a between state?  What does that even look like?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I think you misunderstand the question. OP wants to scroll vertically, with underneath he does not mean they are layered on the Z-axis. He means they are stacked on the Y-axis. Please check this out, https://codepen.io/bluebrown/full/aboagov .  Regardless of how it is achieved, I think OP wants that particular effect. Once you scroll the header of screen you cannot scroll it on screen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

While its not direclty preventing you from scrolling up and its not jQuery, I would suggest to remove/hide the element once its out of view.

You could get the current scroll position, relative to the top of the page, and check if its greater than the elements height:

```
const target = document.getElementById('my-target')
const targetHeight = target.getBoundingClientRect().height

const scrollEventListener = () => {
    if (
      document.body.scrollTop > targetHeight ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > targetHeight
    ) {
        target.remove()
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollEventListener)
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0
      }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEventListener)
```

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/bluebrown/full/aboagov

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out!

Comment: This works really well, the only problem I have is when the `.remove()` function kicks in, the page jumps by the height of the `my-target` div that's being hidden. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @van I can imagine that manually scrolling top will fix this if its browser related.It seems like at least chrome is smart enough to figure out your current view and adjust the scroll position.Maybe some browser does not and simply scrolls the page to the current scroll position which is now a different view because one element is missing. Try adding something like this ` document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0` in the event listener after the remove

Comment: @van ok now I see what you are saying. It is completely related to what I updated in the function. The problem is, when you use your mouse to touch the scrollbar and scroll down, the page will jump because the scrollbar jumps. So to do it properly one had to figure out if the user is pressing the mousekey while this happens, if so, you have to do some positional calculations and adjustments.

Comment: I think its maybe not even possible to do something about the user doing it with mouse and scrollbar instead of simply scrolling. I think the scrollbar position will be always calculated relative to the pages height. You practically had to force the users mouse to a different location. Only thing I could imagine now is disabling the scrollbar but thats bad design.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery scrollTop function like this

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        // set the height in pixels
        if (scroll >= 200) {
         // after the scroll is greater than height then you can remove it or hide it
           $(".intro-image").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try! :)

Answer (score 0):

So instead of *scrolling*, I personally think it would be better to have it be actionable.  Forcing the user to manually do the transition (and all in between states) is a bad idea.  If the user scrolls half way, and see's something actionable (menu, button, input field) is it usable?  If it is, what happens if they submit... very awkward.  If it isn't usable, how do they know when it is?  How do they know it's because they haven't scrolled all the way.  It's very poor user experience.

In the following example, I've created a pseudo-screenport for you to see what's actually going on.  The `.body` container in your real site would be the body element.

[Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/XWrPQwB)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.splash-screen').on('click', function(){
    $('.splash-screen').addClass("is-hidden");
  });
})
```

```css
html, body{
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex-root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.web-container {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #fff;
}
.body {
  font-size: 0; // this is only to prevent spacing between img placholders
  position: relative;
}
.splash-screen{
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
.splash-screen .fa {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15px;
}
.splash-screen.is-hidden {
  transform: translateY(-110%);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-root">
  <div class="web-container">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="splash-screen">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480?text=Splash+Screen"/>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x60/cbcbcb?text=Menu"/>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x420/dddddd?text=Site Body"/>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```